# Adding dictionaries to another

Tags: nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

a silly question:
How do i fit multiple dictionaries together in one or add one to an other?
i tried to initialize my dictionary with two other.. it didn't work.

```
 dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dic2, dic3];
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `addEntriesFromDictionary:dic3` method on `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dic2];
[dic1 addEntriesFromDictionary:dic3];
```